# how to export this value in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the amount received from the request by going to a list and then trying to export it to another file, but I'm having trouble doing this because I tried several ways to pass the list as return and it didn't work.

```
    const moment = require("moment");
    const sslChecker = require("ssl-checker");
    const express = require("express");
    //const dominios = require('./server');
    
    var dominios = [
      "api-prd.koerich.com.br",
      "api-prd.reservapto.com.br",
      "c.btg360.com.br",
      "compassouol.com",
      "gmfy.compasso.com.br",
      "webqplus.cbn.com.bo",
      "webqplus.cerchile.cl",
      "webqplus.cervepar.com.py",
      "webqplus.fnc.com.uy",
      "webqplus.quilmes.com.ar",
      "www.efurukawa.com",
    ];
    
    var get_domain = dominios;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < get_domain.length; i++) {
      sslChecker(get_domain[i])
        .then((certdata) => {
          var startdate = new Date(certdata.validFrom);
          var enddate = new Date(certdata.validTo);
          var certstart = moment(startdate);
          var certend = moment(enddate);
          var ssldata = [
            {
              domain: get_domain,
              issued: certstart.format("LLLL"),
              expires: certend.format("LLLL"),
              daysleft: certdata.daysRemaining,
            },
          ];
          var data = JSON.parse(certdata.daysRemaining);
          var nomes = (certdata.validFor[0]);
          var lista = [];
          lista.push(data);
          lista.push(nomes);
          console.log(lista);     //get this values
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err); 
        });
    }
    
    //module.exports = lista;  //export here
```

console.log:
[image]

Comment: You can't just export it because you have an asynchronous operation to build the list in the first place. All you can do is export a function to be called to get the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function getList() {
  mondongo = [];
  var dominios = [
  "api-prd.koerich.com.br",
  "api-prd.reservapto.com.br",
  "c.btg360.com.br",
  "compassouol.com",
  "gmfy.compasso.com.br",
  "webqplus.cbn.com.bo",
  "webqplus.cerchile.cl",
  "webqplus.cervepar.com.py",
  "webqplus.fnc.com.uy",
  "webqplus.quilmes.com.ar",
  "www.efurukawa.com",
]
  try {
    
    for (var i = 2; i < domains.length; i++) {
      mondongo.push(
        sslChecker(domains[i])
          .then((certdata) => {
            var startdate = new Date(certdata.validFrom);
            var enddate = new Date(certdata.validTo);
            var certstart = moment(startdate);
            var certend = moment(enddate);
            var ssldata = [
              {
                domain: domains,
                issued: certstart.format("LLLL"),
                expires: certend.format("LLLL"),
                daysleft: certdata.daysRemaining,
              },
            ];
            var data = certdata.daysRemaining;
            var nome = certdata.validFor[0];
            var lista = [];
            lista.push(nome);
            lista.push(data);
            return lista;
          })

          .catch((err) => {
            //console.log(err);
          })
      );
    }
    
  } 
   catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  var arroz = await Promise.all(mondongo);
  return arroz;
}
```

return:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

create a function and use the async await methods.